# Can i have two clients use DJI onboard SDK to talk with the craft?

Tags: dji-sdk

Can i have two clients use DJI onboard SDK to talk with the craft?

For example, one to read the flight data, and another to set command to craft.

Answer (score 0):

Not officially supported.

You could engineer a solution that involves your 'read' client merely sniffing the UART line for broadcast data, and your 'write' client implementing a full bidirectional communication. You do not need to obtain control of the aircraft to receive broadcast data, so this solution could work.

Bear in mind though that adding a fragile sniffing solution will give you low robustness and should be used with extreme caution on a flying robot.